# Python Mock Autospec vs Spec

Tags: python-2.7, mocking, python-unittest

Trying to wrap my head around the difference between Spec and Autospec. They seem to be about the same. Specifically, if you look at mock.patch decorator.

Can someone explain when to use which?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`spec` is used as a template for your Mock object. In the words of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock):

> If you use the spec or spec_set arguments then only magic methods that exist in the spec will be created.

This means that you cannot call methods on the mock object that do not exist on the object you are mocking. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) explains this like this:

> Note If you use the spec keyword argument to create a mock then attempting to set a magic method that isn’t in the spec will raise an AttributeError.

`autospec` is basically a shorthand in `patch` for passing in the object your patching to the `spec` of the `MagicMock` being created. Documentation:

> If you set autospec=True then the mock with be created with a spec from the object being replaced.

Answer (score 6):

`spec` applies only to the mock instance where it is specified. In particular, if the mocked class `a` has a method, e.g. `method()`, then calling that method in the instanciated mock of `a` will automatically generate and return another mock that is not restricted to any spec. This is where `autospec` comes in handy, as it recursively defines specs on whatever is called (within the restrictions of the specs defined up to that point).

From the [Mock Autospeccing Helper documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing):

> If you use a class or instance as the spec for a mock then you can only access attributes on the mock that exist on the real class:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> mock = Mock(spec=urllib2.Request)
>>> mock.assret_called_with
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'assret_called_with'
```

> The spec only applies to the mock itself, so we still have the same issue with any methods on the mock:

```
>>> mock.has_data()
<mock.Mock object at 0x...>
>>> mock.has_data.assret_called_with()
```

> Auto-speccing solves this problem.

Comment: "calling that method in the instantiated mock of `a` will automatically generate and return another mock that is not restricted to any spec"—technically, this is also a problem with `create_autospec`. `create_autospec` only recursively autospecs attributes, not method return values.

Comment: Just as @BrianMcCutchon pointed out, this answer might be misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Without `spec` and `autospec`, the mock object **doesn't have the attributes** from the target.

With `spec=True`, the mock object has the attributes from the target, but the type of these attributes is simply `MagicMock` **without a spec**.

With `autospec=True`, the mock object has the attributes from the target and the type of these attributes is `MagicMock`, these mock attributes also **have their own specs**.

The following code shows the differences:

```
from unittest import mock
import inspect


class Bar:
  def __init__(self, id: int):
    self.id = id

  def f(name: str):
    return f'id={id}, name={name}'

class Foo:
  def g(self, bar: Bar) -> Bar:
    print(bar.f('world'))
    return bar

def main() -> None:
  print('Mock without spec')
  with mock.patch(f'{Foo.__module__}.Foo') as foo:
    print(f'dir(foo): {dir(foo)}') # `g` is not defined
    g = getattr(foo, 'g') # `g` is defined when being accessed
    print(f'foo.g signature: {inspect.signature(g)}')
    print('\n')

  print('Mock with spec')
  with mock.patch(f'{Foo.__module__}.Foo', spec=True) as foo:
    print(f'dir(foo): {dir(foo)}') # `g` is defined without a spec
    g = getattr(foo, 'g')
    print(f'foo.g signature: {inspect.signature(g)}')
    print('\n')

  print('Mock with autospec')
  with mock.patch(f'{Foo.__module__}.Foo', autospec=True) as foo:
    print(f'dir(foo): {dir(foo)}') # `g` is defined with a spec
    g = getattr(foo, 'g')
    print(f'foo.g signature: {inspect.signature(g)}')
    print('\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Output:

```
Mock without spec
dir(foo): ['assert_any_call', 'assert_called', 'assert_called_once', 'assert_called_once_with', 'assert_called_with', 'assert_has_calls', 'assert_not_called', 'attach_mock', 'call_args', 'call_args_list', 'call_count', 'called', 'configure_mock', 'method_calls', 'mock_add_spec', 'mock_calls', 'reset_mock', 'return_value', 'side_effect']
foo.g signature: (*args, **kwargs)


Mock with spec
dir(foo): ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'assert_any_call', 'assert_called', 'assert_called_once', 'assert_called_once_with', 'assert_called_with', 'assert_has_calls', 'assert_not_called', 'attach_mock', 'call_args', 'call_args_list', 'call_count', 'called', 'configure_mock', 'g', 'method_calls', 'mock_add_spec', 'mock_calls', 'reset_mock', 'return_value', 'side_effect']
foo.g signature: (*args, **kwargs)


Mock with autospec
dir(foo): ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'assert_any_call', 'assert_called', 'assert_called_once', 'assert_called_once_with', 'assert_called_with', 'assert_has_calls', 'assert_not_called', 'attach_mock', 'call_args', 'call_args_list', 'call_count', 'called', 'configure_mock', 'g', 'method_calls', 'mock_add_spec', 'mock_calls', 'reset_mock', 'return_value', 'side_effect']
foo.g signature: (bar: __main__.Bar) -> __main__.Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

I will explain it on the [unittest.mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), since it has two options the `spec`, which expected to be object to use as a specification for mock and `autospec` - similar to spec, except it will provide spec for all "child" mocks of the spec object, below is illustration for those use cases:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, create_autospec, patch
from unittest import TestCase


class MyClass:
    
    @staticmethod
    def method(foo, bar):
        print(foo)


def some_method(some_class: MyClass):
    arg = 1
    # Would fail because of wrong parameters passed to method.
    return some_class.method(arg)


class TestSomethingTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_something_with_patch_spec(self):
        with patch(f'{__name__}.MyClass', spec=True) as mock:
            # Fails because of signature misuse.
            result = some_method(mock)
        self.assertTrue(result)
        self.assertTrue(mock.method.called)
    
    def test_second_with_patch_autospec(self):
        with patch(f'{__name__}.MyClass', autospec=True) as mock:
            # Fails because of signature misuse.
            result = some_method(mock)
        self.assertTrue(result)
        self.assertTrue(mock.method.called)
```

Th test case with autospec will catch the bug in the code, because `MyClass.method` signature doesn't correspond to one expected on `some_method`, which is anticipated, whereas `test_something_with_patch_spec` with spec usage will give you **false positive**, so test wouldn't fulfill its duties.

The [unittest.mock.Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) has only spec option, as an alternative you can use [unittest.mock.create_autospec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.create_autospec), so it will create Mock with autospec effect described in example above.

Comment: That's a good example, thank you! I'd suggest to change the comment in `test_something_with_patch_spec` as it is misleading, as nothing fails in that case, which is exactly what you wanted to prove :)